# How can I change the keybindings to switch windows in Byobu?

Tags: byobu

I'm using Byobu 5.73. The tmux keybindings to switch windows is *ALT + Left arrow* and *ALT + Right arrow*.  I want to change this keybinding for *CTRL + SHIFT + Left arrow* and *CTRL + SHIFT + Right arrow*.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One way to do it is to edit `/usr/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux`.

You will find these lines :

```
bind-key -n M-Left previous-window
bind-key -n M-Right next-window
```

`M` is for *Meta*, aka the *ALT key*.  Change the lines for :

```
bind-key -n C-S-Left previous-window
bind-key -n C-S-Right next-window
```

`C` for *Ctrl key* and `S` for *Shift key*.

Save, quit, press F5 to reload profile.

Refs : [Bybobu doc](http://byobu.co/documentation.html), [Byobu-and-mc](http://dodoincfedora.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/byobu-and-mc/), [keybindings-in-byobu-using-tmux-backend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330374/disable-keybindings-in-byobu-using-tmux-backend), [tmux](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/tmux.1.html)

Comment: +1... also: to make the changes at the user level, make the same edit to ~/.byobu/keybindings.tmux